# Xamarin System.Json can't parse JSON string into JsonValue object

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, imgur

I'm using Xamarin Studio on MacOSX and working on a iOS test project.

I'm making a Http request to upload an image to Imgur and then try to parse the response when it finishes. The upload is performed successfully but when I try to parse the string response, I get the error message:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'`

But the JSON string I get looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "EGpAY43",
    "title": "adasd",
    "description": "eqeqwd",
    "datetime": 1412635648,
    "type": "image\/png",
    "animated": false,
    "width": 480,
    "height": 360,
    "size": 343319,
    "views": 0,
    "bandwidth": 0,
    "vote": null,
    "favorite": false,
    "nsfw": null,
    "section": null,
    "account_url": null,
    "deletehash": "qAXQgXXuAZ91sJS",
    "link": "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/EGpAY43.png"
  },
  "success": true,
  "status": 200
}
```

As you can see that's a correct JSON string, but for some reason I don't understand it can't be parsed.

The code I use to upload an image looks like this:

```
    protected async void UploadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e){
        var title = TitleTxt.Text;
        var description = DescriptionTxt.Text;
        var image = SelectionImg.Image;

        var imageBytes = image.AsPNG ().ToArray();

        string response = await UploadImage (title, description, imageBytes);

        try{
            var jsonResponse = JsonObject.Parse (response);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine ("Error " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine ("Http Request response " + response);
        }
    }

    protected async Task<string> UploadImage(string title, string description, byte[] imageBytes){
        Console.WriteLine ("Upload image");
        var url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create (url);
        request.Headers.Add ("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = 10000;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream ();

        string parameters = "image=" + Convert.ToBase64String (imageBytes);
        parameters += "&" + "title=" + title;
        parameters += "&" + "description=" + description;

        byte[] byteParams = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (parameters);
        requestStream.Write (byteParams, 0, byteParams.Length);
        requestStream.Close ();
        try{
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (responseStream)) {
                    string content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
                    Console.WriteLine (content);
                    return content;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I return the string value without modifications on my part, or am I doing something wrong in my code?

**EDIT 1**

I tried this on Android and it failed too at parsing, but the message was a little different:

`Cannot cast from source type to destination type`

The code I used was the same (as you can see I'm not using platform specific stuff since this code I want to use it in a PCL).

The odd part is that I tried to use a different code to upload this and the parsing didn't fail.

The code I tried was this:

```
    protected void UploadImage(string title, string description, byte[] imageBytes){

        NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection ();
        postData.Add ("image", Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes));
        postData.Add ("title", title);
        postData.Add ("description", description);

        WebClient client = new WebClient ();
        client.Headers.Add ("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
        client.UploadValuesCompleted += new UploadValuesCompletedEventHandler(ReadStreamFromResponse);
        client.UploadValuesAsync (new Uri("https://api.imgur.com/3/image"), "POST", postData);
    }

    private void ReadStreamFromResponse(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e){
        string content = Encoding.Default.GetString (e.Result);
        try{
            // Parsing is done without problems
            var json = JsonObject.Parse (content);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine ("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what is the problem, the Imgur response for an image upload can't be parsed on one, but on using the second code it can be done.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I get the byte array from the response.

What could cause this behaviour?

**EDIT 2**

I made some changes to my code, I was puzzled as to why one implementation parses correctly and the other not. So I tried to make it capable of being used in a PCL. I ended up with this:

My function to upload an image to Imgur using API v3:

```
    public async Task<WebResponse> UploadImage(byte[] imageBytes){
        // Since I'm making anonymous upload then I have no need of the other parameters
        // also some photos don't upload correctly with those perhaps something to do with what user L.B referred to me
        string parameters = Convert.ToBase64String (imageBytes);
        byte[] byteParams = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (parameters);

        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp ("https://api.imgur.com/3/image");

        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Client-ID " + clientId;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";


        using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync (
                  request.BeginGetRequestStream,
                  request.EndGetRequestStream,
            (object)null)) {

            await requestStream.WriteAsync (byteParams, 0, byteParams.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync (request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request);
        return response;
    }
```

Method that handles the click event:

```
    protected async void UploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
        // only focusing on upload the image
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) selectedImg.Drawable;
        byte[] imageBytes;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.Bitmap;
            bitmap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            imageBytes = stream.ToArray ();
        }
        // wait for the response then pass it to ReadStreamFromResponse
        WebResponse response = await UploadImage (imageBytes);
        ReadStreamFromResponse (response);
    }
```

Method that reads the stream from the WebResponse:

```
    private void ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response){
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream ()) {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (responseStream)) {
                string content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
                try{
                // This is parsed successfully
                    var json = JsonObject.Parse (content);

                } catch(Exception ex){
                    Console.WriteLine ("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

While this implementation uploads the image and parses correctly, I haven't been able to identify the root of my problem. I need to identify it so I can understand what am I doing wrong and avoid it next time.

Comment: As a side note: What happens when you type `&image=` to `TitleTxt` :)

Comment: Which line of code is the casting exception thrown at?

Comment: @L.B what do you mean by typing `&image=`to TitleTxt? Do you mean setting the Textfield value to the image binary-to-string value?
@Rich on the method UploadHandler inside the try-catch block.

Comment: @UrielArvizu You don't escape the values while forming `parameters`, you will get an invalid string. Just try to type that 7 chars to your textbox.

Comment: @L.B I don't understand where you're coming from, so I type `&image=`in the text field will cause a bad request since I'm not validating that in my code yet.

I think you're misunderstanding my problem. I can upload the images successfully, my problem is that I'm not able to parse the response I get from the response for some reason. I updated my code showing another way to upload the image, but that response can be parsed, since the way I retrieve the response is different, I'm guessing that's where my problem lies, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @UrielArvizu `you're misunderstanding my problem`, No I think you misunderstood me. See my very first comment starts with *As a side note*, just to inform your another possible bug.

Comment: @L.B if I type &image= into TitleTxt and try to upload an image I get a bad request response with status code 400.